Interactive Azure Login from Maui Android App Doesn't Work
The Azure login in the Maui version of our app does not work.  It works fine with Xamarin (for the past 4 years).   With Maui, when we go through the Azure sign in, we are never prompted for the application.  Instead, it just bounces back to the app, without issuing a token.
This illustrates the problem:

As shown above, when launching the sequence from Xamarin, the final step is a prompt to select the application "Just Once" or "Always".  For some weird reason, that final step never occurs from the MAUI version of the app.
The code in the app to launch the sequence looks like this:
 try
 {
     AuthResult = await PCA.AcquireTokenInteractive(_scopes)
         .WithAuthority(AUTHORITY_URI)
         .WithParentActivityOrWindow(theParentWindow)
         .WithPrompt(Prompt.ForceLogin)
         .ExecuteAsync();

 }
 catch (Exception ex2)
 {
     SetAuthToken(null);
     throw new ApplicationException("Interactive login failed", ex2);
 }

 SetAuthToken(AuthResult?.AccessToken);

The manifest under Xamarin looks like this
    <application android:label="Our App" android:icon="@drawable/Logo_Sized" android:debuggable="true" android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config">
        <activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="msal5af1aeaa-5a52-4699-8273-ec10b68ebfb2" android:host="auth" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.company.ourapp.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

The manifest under MAUI is basically identical:
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/app_logo" android:supportsRtl="true" android:label="Our App" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name="microsoft.identity.client.BrowserTabActivity" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data android:scheme="msal5af1aeaa-5a52-4699-8273-ec10b68ebfb2" android:host="auth" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <provider android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.company.ourapp.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>

I have no idea why the behavior in Azure would be different when launched from Xamarin vs the Maui version of the app.
Can anyone spot what might be different with the Maui version?

Found the problem here. The MsalActivity was not included in the ported Maui project.  Adding that class along with line of code in MainActivity to continue the authorization solved the problem:
    [Activity( Exported=true )]
    [IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionView },
        Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
        DataHost = "auth",
        DataScheme = "msal5af1aeaa-5a52-4699-8273-ec10b68ebfb2")]
    public class MsalActivity : BrowserTabActivity
    {
    }

The code in MainActivity...
      protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent? data)
      {
         // this was already here...
         if (requestCode == CheckPermissionManager.CheckPermission.RequestCode)
            CheckPermissionManager.CheckPermission.OnActivityResult();
            
         base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
         
         // added this...
AuthenticationContinuationHelper.SetAuthenticationContinuationEventArgs(requestCode, resultCode, data);

      }

